# Can you use a jQuery selector on a HTML tag that a JS string printed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

Sorry if the question was misleading, I couldn't find a better way to describe my problem. Anyway, here goes:

Suppose I had a button `start` that initially displays a string for me. Said string (let's call it `stringA`) is output through jQuery like this:

```
$(".start").click(function() {
    $(".startButton").hide('slow', function() {
        $("#table1").html(stringA);
    });
});
```

Alright. Cool. That worked without a hitch. Now inside `stringA` I have multiple
`<span class="optButton">this is a button</span>` buttons. I have another onClick handler for my `optButton` button, and it goes like this:

```
$(".optButton").click(function() {
    alert("Testing");
    $("#table1").html(stringB);
});
```

Needless to say, clicking on `optButton` is supposed to replace the contents of `#table1` with `stringB`. However, when I tried it, it doesn't work. I tried adding `alert()` to test and see if jQuery managed to select `optButton`, but it seems that it didn't because I get no popup from the `alert()` function.

My theory is that since `optButton` was not part of the original HTML and is within a string `stringA`, jQuery is unable to select `optButton` as a result. If this is true, is there a workaround to this issue? If it is not, what is the actual cause of the problem here?

Comment: Felix answer is right. Since the element .optButton did not exist in the first place, the click handler was binded to nothing. To prevent that, use delegation (= .on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since your `span` element has been dynamically added to the DOM:

```
$('#table1').on('click', '.optButton', function() {
    alert("Testing");
    $("#table1").html(stringB);
});
```

This technique will helps you to attach click handler to these newly created `span` elements.

Comment: Another way would be to add the click listener when the content is added, but this is clearer.

Comment: @Felix Thank you so much! 10 internets as well for the link to the documentation!